# A Possibly Divergent Improper Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am to evaluate the integral $$I = \int_{-1}^0 \frac{\exp(\frac{1}{x})}{x^3}\mathrm{d}x.$$ The indefinite integral I worked out as $(1-\frac{1}{x})\exp(\frac{1}{x}) + C.$ I attempted to evaluate the upper limit point with this antiderivative and got $\infty$, which I took to mean that the integral diverged. But [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20exp%281%2Fx%29%2Fx%5E3%20from%20-1%20to%200) shows that this integral is $-2e^{-1}.$ I cannot see where my calculation goes wrong. Also, shouldn't one expect the integrand to blow up near zero? The graph drawn there seems to flatten out at $0$.

Comment: It matters how you approach it! As $x\to 0$ from the left, $1/x$ is large and negative, so $\exp(1/x)$ approaches *zero*, fast enough to negate $(1-1/x)$ getting large.

Comment: Another approach: substitute $z=-1/x$. Then you have $I= -\int _{1}^{\infty} z e^{-z}\,dz$, which can be integrated (check out the gamma function) using IBP, and the behavior of the limits might be clearer now.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly where I went wrong.

Comment: @Integrand Would the Gamma function be helpful here? I assumed the integral there is from 0 to $\infty$... I'd do it using the Feynman trick: solving $\int_1^\infty e^{-a z}\text{d}z$, then differentiating with respect to $a$ and setting $a=1$.

Comment: @Phillip, no the bounds are correct. I'm just mentioning it because it's related.